# Start Google map Marker at GPS, but draggable - fills in form

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, google-api, maps

I am finishing up a project I'm working on, and to improve user functionality, I want to have a page where the browser gets the user's current position (geolocation()), and fills out form fields with the latitude and longitude. However, once that happens, I want a marker placed on a google map that the user can drag, which will update in the form when they drag it. I know there has to be a way to do this, but I can't quite get it working. As of now, I have it fully functional to grab the user's location and fill out the form fields. I'm kind of struggling with the Google API, though. It doesn't help I'm not very well versed in Javascript (These functionalities are pretty much the only javascript I'm using throughout the whole large project). Attached is working code that gets position and fills out the input fields, and then I have my first attack at the Google maps API, which fails: The map simply comes up as a blank gray box with the zoom controls and street-view dragger, but they do nothing since it's all gray.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("latitude");
var y=document.getElementById("longitude");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position) {
  x.value=position.coords.latitude;  
  y.value=position.coords.longitude;    
}
getLocation();
```

and here's the google api stuff that's failing (keeping in mind that this is just a hacked together attempt that I kind of figured wouldn't work). I'm wondering if the x and y values aren't immediately filling out and this is then getting called somehow, because if I hard-code in latitudes and longitudes instead of x and y, I get a functional map, although, obviously since x and y aren't being used there, it doesn't fill back in the form:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

Finally, here's my two fields of the input form:
<p>
    <i>Latitude:</i>
    <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude"><br>
</p>
<p>
    <i>Longitude:</i>
    <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude"><br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do

```
<style>
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<p>
  <i>Latitude:</i>
  <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude"><br>
</p>
<p>
  <i>Longitude:</i>
  <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude"><br>
</p>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("latitude");
var y=document.getElementById("longitude");
// Make sure you have a default.  You don't know if geolocation will find the user's location
var defaultLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(50.84498962150941, 4.349988162517548);  // Manneken Pis, Brussels
var map;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
  else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    ////maybe you want to set a marker on the map anyway.
    // markerOnClientPosition(defaultLocation);
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  x.value = position.coords.latitude;
  y.value = position.coords.longitude;
  if (map) {
    markerOnClientPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
  }
}
getLocation();
function initialize() {
  //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(x), Number(y));  //
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: defaultLocation, // myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
function markerOnClientPosition(myLatlng) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'You are here.  Drag to exact location'
  });
  // attach a drag event
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    x.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    y.value = marker.getPosition().lng();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Emmanuel. I was able to get something functional put together, although I'm having some odd things happen at the moment. If I can't track them down I'll drop your code in. Looks like it should work, and it's certainly cleaner than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I always seem to solve things *after* I ask about them. After more digging, I found this page's top solution to be tailorable to my project.

[Google Maps v3: need multiple draggable markers to update HTML input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510781/google-maps-v3-need-multiple-draggable-markers-to-update-html-input-fields?rq=1)